# Number of possible interleavings of two strings of lengths m and n

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given two strings, str1 = "AB",  str2 = "CD"

The interleavings are
    ABCD
    ACBD
    ACDB
    CABD
    CADB
    CDAB,

I'd like to know if there is a general formula I can come up with in terms of m and n to see how many possible such interleavings exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all characters are distinguishable, the answer is $m+n\choose n$.

Comment: perfect. thanks